# Женской род слова "партнёр"

Tags: грамотная-речь, недопустимая-метка

Можно ли сказать "партнёрша"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь всё зависит от значения слова. Если имеется в виду "по половой связи", "по танцу", то уместно будет употребить слово в женском роде - "*партнёрша*" (оно есть в орфографическом словаре Ожегова и Шапиро (и указано без пометки о разговорности). Но в других случаях, и уж особенно в официально-деловом стиле речи, следует употреблять только "партнёр", вне зависимости от пола. Например, *партнёр по бизнесу*, *партнёр по шахматам*. В этих значениях слово "партнёрша" считается неуместным и употребляется только в разговорной речи.